# Failed to resolve compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting errors "Failed to resolve", doesn't support libraries starting from version 26.0.1. My Android Studio version is 2.3.3

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pp.pos"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

When I add Google's Maven repository to your project's build.gradle file,

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest merger failed,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.0.1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v0wM.png)

Comment: Show your project level build.gradle. I think, that you forgot to add new repo. Also post Gradle version (see in `gradle-wrapper.properties`)

Comment: What u want to see? I don't understand clearly. SDK Platforms/SDK Tools ?

Comment: I want to see repositories section

Comment: I was facing same problem,  i tried changing this [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1]  with [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0] and  buildToolsVersion "26.0.1" with  buildToolsVersion "26.0.0" now its working fine for me :-)